# Limit data returned by GetListItems of Lists.asmx service with CAML

Tags: 2010, caml-query, soap

I want to limit data returned by GetListItems of Lists.asmx service. Does anyone know why despite the query options below I get **all** items?

```
"<GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">"
    "<listName>Documents</listName>"
    "<viewFields>"
        "<ViewFields>"
            "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>"
        "</ViewFields>"
    "</viewFields>"
    "<queryOptions>"
        "<QueryOptions>"
            "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>"
            "<ViewFieldsOnly>TRUE</ViewFieldsOnly>"
        "</QueryOptions>"
    "</queryOptions>"
"</GetListItems>"
```

Answer (score 1):

[GetListItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586530(v=office.11).aspx) method accepts a parameter `RowLimit` to limit the number of items retrieved.

`rowLimit` - A string that specifies the number of items, or rows, to display on a page before paging begins. If supplied, the value of this parameter overrides the row limit set in the view specified by the `viewName` parameter or the row limit set in the default view for the list.

```
"<GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">"
    "<listName>Documents</listName>"
    "<viewFields>"
        "<ViewFields>"
            "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>"
        "</ViewFields>"
    "</viewFields>"
    "<queryOptions>"
        "<QueryOptions>"
            "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>"
            "<ViewFieldsOnly>TRUE</ViewFieldsOnly>"
        "</QueryOptions>"
    "</queryOptions>"
    "<rowLimit">
        "10"
    "</rowLimit>"
"</GetListItems>"
```

Comment: Row Limit only take care of the rows. While ViewFields will limit the fields.

Comment: How `rowLimit` should make the server return only those fields listed in `<ViewFieldsOnly>`? My result should contain **all** items from query (if I use them). The task is to show only ID for each item (row).

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889900/how-to-return-only-certain-columns-of-a-list-when-using-the-sharepoint-web-servi

Comment: I have tried `<rowLimit>1</rowLimit>` and (as expected) it limits **rows** but not **columns**

Comment: Please read the link i provided. ROWLIMIT only limits number of ROWS and not COLUMNS. For limiting columns you need to use <ViewFieldsOnly>.. but as per my above comment, the link says its a bug..

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line after `</viewFields>` or `</queryOptions>`:

```
<rowLimit>1</rowLimit>
```

Keep in mind that it's case sensitive.

Your query should look like this:

`"<GetListItems xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/\">"
    "<listName>Documents</listName>"
    "<viewFields>"
        "<ViewFields>"
            "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>"
        "</ViewFields>"
    "</viewFields>"
    "<rowLimit>1</rowLimit>"
    "<queryOptions>"
        "<QueryOptions>"
            "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>"
            "<ViewFieldsOnly>TRUE</ViewFieldsOnly>"
        "</QueryOptions>"
    "</queryOptions>"
"</GetListItems>"`

More information on GetListItems method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd586530%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: look at my comment to previous post